# JQuery function to select checkboxes

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

I need a function that accepts a parameter with its id example a div 
and after that loops inside the div to look for checkboxes and if there is/are any checks if its value is checked and returns true if every checkbox is checked returns false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully I've understood you correctly. This is what I think you've asked for: a function that takes an element ID and returns `false` if the corresponding element contains any checked checkboxes and `true` otherwise.

Here's a no-library version. It will be faster and work in more browsers than a jQuery version.

```
function containsNoCheckedCheckboxes(id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    if (el) {
        var inputs = el.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; ++i) {
            if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox" && inputs[i].checked) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very mutch just what i needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
$('#parent:has(input:checkbox:checked)')
```

If you find any elements you can retrun true, for example by `.is('*')` or `.length == 1`

You can write a function, or even a tiny plugin:

```
$.fn.extend({   
     hasCheckedBoxes: function() {  
       return this.has('input:checkbox:checked').is('*');
     }  
});
```

This can be used as:

```
if($('#Documents').hasCheckedBoxes()) //`#Documents` contains a checked box.
```

or

```
if($('div').hasCheckedBoxes()) //true if any `<p>` contains a checked box.
```